# What were the animated loops supposed to be?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

What were the animated loops in the movie *Thor: The Dark World* supposed to be?

Were they wormholes? And what was the Aether proposed in there?

Comment: Can you give a better reference as to what you are talking about? What part of the movie? Maybe a screen capture?

Answer (score 2):

They are portals for connecting to other [realms](http://marvel-cinematic-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Nine_Realms), 9 for now.

The things which didn’t return from the loop are shown in other realms in the movie later.

And portals were created due to Convergence.

> During the Convergence, the Nine Realms of Yggdrasil are in alignment.
>   This alignment causes the dimensional boundaries between each realm to
>   become thin, resulting in various physical anomalies occurring at
>   random. These phenomena include shifts in gravity, spatial extrusions,
>   and the fabric of reality possibly tearing apart. Perhaps most
>   notably, invisible wormholes that allow matter to move between realms
>   are seemingly born and evaporate at random. - (Source:[marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Convergence))

Aether just got discovered due to Convergence.